# width 100% minus margin with parent `flex-direction: column`

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<form>` inside of a `<div>`

```html
<div>
  <form></form>
</div>
```

I want the `<form>` to take up 100% of the parent width taking into account margin and padding. I achieve this by setting `box-sizing: border-box`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
form {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

This works. However, in my use case I need the parent `div` to have `flex-direction: column`, as `<form>` will have a sibling `<section>` *above* it,

```html
<div>
  <section></section>
  <form></form>
</div>
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
form {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

This breaks the desired behavior. The `<form>` now takes up 100% of the horizontal space, and margin goes outside of it's parent boundary.

This is the desired effect

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to `align-items: center;` in `div` with `flex-direction: column;`, you can remove `width` in `form`, and just add `align-self: stretch;`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* for demonstration */
  min-height: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
}

section {
  /* for demonstration */
  min-height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  align-self: stretch;
}

form {
  margin: 50px;
  align-self: stretch; /*  */
  /* for demonstration */
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>Section</section>
  <form>Form</form>
</div>
```